# Waiting for DIV to stop moving before proceeding to another page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, razor

I have a jQuery function on my page that animates a div (slides it up) when the user clicks on a Link. But I want the browser to go to the linked page only after the DIV has finished sliding up. Can we do this?

Does anyone have any references/articles/tutorials?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a javascript redirect in the callback of the slideUp method.

Example:

```
$('#divId').click(function() {
  $(this).slideUp('slow', function() {
    window.location = 'urlhere'; //relative url
  });
});
```

Or if the url is outside of the site, you replace the `window.location` with this:

```
 window.location = 'http://domainhere.com/urlhere'; //absolute url
```

Comment: Alot more straight forward than my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you've done the sliding, I personally would create a function:

if you follow the jQuery documentation

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    window.location = 'http://example.com'
  });
});
```

If you provide code or more detail and can be more specific

Comment: In your first example, the window.location would execute right away. You'd need to send it in as a function: $('#example').slideUp('slow', function(){ window.location = 'http://example.com'; });

Comment: hence my second example :), I'll edit the answer to delete the first example

Comment: Oh, cool. I wasn't clear (to me, at least) that it was showing not to do that :)

Comment: No you're right it was an example but I didn't test it. Anyway its gone now \o/

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a callback function that is called when the animation or effect completes.  See [this page](http://jqueryui.com/docs/effect/) - and click on view source for an example